# How do I create horizontal bar on page background with CSS but no image?

Tags: css, background, background-color

I am trying to make a very simple gray background bar on the page. The bar should be 81 pixels from page top and height of the bar should be 71 pixels.

I can do this with an image file and background-repeat:x. Such as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/G29vE/ or the code below (image file removed):

```
body {
  width:             100px;
  height:            100px;
  background-image:  url('data:image/png;base64,...');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin:            0px;
  padding:           0px;
}
```

But it seems unnecessary to include (or link to) the image file. I wonder - and am asking - if this could be done pure CSS (or CSS3)? I could not find an answer or similar example from Google or SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a div and style it as you want:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bar {
    width:            100%;
    height:           71px;
    background:       #DDD;
    margin-top:       81px;
    padding:          0px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/G29vE/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Added `z-index:-10000` and `position:absolute` to your CSS to make the bar really go into background... Solved!

Answer (score 2):

You can use linear-gradient() for the bar color and use background-size to limit its height:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfe0e1, #dfe0e1) 0 81px / 100% 71px no-repeat #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Div with a z-index.
This div can you give it's own css style

Answer (score 0):

Simply placed a div with id or class..

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
```

and placed css code in stylesheet

```
#topbar { position:absolute; z-index:9; height:71px; top:81px; left:10px; right:10px; background:#ccc;   }
```

this not only float you div as a top bar but also extend to you browser 100%.